# Is there a way to pass a custom file path to warp::fs::file?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'd like to build a custom path, then download a file at that path. Eg,

```rust
        warp::path!("files" / u32)
            .map(|fileId| {
                format!("{}.txt", *FILES_PATH, fileId)
            })
            .and(warp::fs::file)
```

But I get an error like:

```
the trait bound 'fn(_) -> 
    impl warp::filter::FilterClone {
      warp::filters::fs::file::<_>
    }: warp::filter::FilterBase' is not satisfied
```

Am I missing an easy way that this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In warp, filters cannot be dynamically generated, they must be created when the program starts up. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/pull/92) to support this, but it hasn't seen activity in a while.

Your best option is to copy [Warp's implementation of file paths](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.5/src/warp/filters/fs.rs.html#259) - it uses Warp-internal code, so you'd have to define your own error and rejection types, but that's not too difficult.

Comment: Hm, is it true that there isn't a facility to write custom filters? The FilterBase trait seems to be private. Is this something one should use `.and_then` for?

Comment: Yes, custom filters must be implemented with `and_then` and `impl Filter`.